# Webservices - Configuring JSON for RESTful webservices in Java

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, maven

Iam new to webservices and Iam trying to create a restful webservice invoking JSON data. After searching I thought I could use maven to create a webservice and used this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/configuring_json_for_restful_web) to create a webservice. I installed maven and tried to repeat the same steps given in the link. But when I run the application I get the below error.

**"Failed to execute goal on project printer-status-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies forproject com.example:printer-status-webapp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.sun.jersey:jersey-grizzly:jar:1.0 in glassfish.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish) "**

I have tomcat running in my machine. I have not installed glassfish. Is it not possible to run the application with tomcat itself.

Anybody pls help me resolve this error.

Else any simple example for creating restful webservices with json data will also be helpful

Pls find the pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>printer-status-webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>printer-status-webapp</name>
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- uncomment this to get Fastinfoset support:
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-fastinfoset</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- uncomment this to get ATOM support:
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-atom</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- uncomment this to get multipart MIME types support:
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-servlet-webserver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <url>http://172.16.109.209:8080/manager</url>
        <server>mytomcat</server>
        <path>/mywebapp</path>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <jersey-version>1.0</jersey-version>
</properties>
 <!-- <repositories>
   <repository>
        <id>glassfish.java.net</id>
        <name>GlassFish Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository> 
    <repository>
        <id>m2.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        <layout>default</layout> 
    </repository> 
</repositories>  -->
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml?

Comment: I have added the pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

The error is basically telling you that maven is looking for the dependency "com.sun.jersey:jersey-grizzly:jar:1.0" in the repository "http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish" that is your pom.xml and it can not find it.

Do you try it with the Maven Central Repository??

Comment: Can you please tell me how to try with Maven Central repository

Answer (score 0):

Adding Maven central repository:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```